# Is there an alternative to the "Pi Store" for Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian

I'm not satisfied with the Pi Store's software solutions. Do I have any alternatives to choose from?

For instance, I'm looking for web browsers and an IDE and it would be convenient to grab these from a store like app within Raspbian.

Comment: Have you used apt-get before? What browser do you want, an IDE for what language?

Comment: I have. I'm not entirely sure how it works though. I'm looking for anything really. But I'd prefer a build of Chromium or Firefox and maybe something like Geany for an IDE

Comment: Is apt-get my only alternative?

Comment: No but it has hundreds if not thousands of more packages. And it is worth the time needed to learn the basics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**apt-get basics**

the following command will update the list of available packages.

```
  sudo apt-get update
```

this is normally followed by:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

which will update the installed packages.

Once this is done you can install additional packages with the following:

```
sudo apt-get install package-name
```

where package-name is replaced with the name of the package you want to install. So to install chromium you would enter:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

likewise to install geany:

```
sudo apt-get install geany.
```

Finally to get help with apt-get or almost any command you can enter

```
man apt-get
```

This will display the man (manual) page.

There is a graphical tool Aptitude Package Manager available from the **Other** menu which provides largely the same functionality.

You may also want to look for a book that coers Linux basics (I can recommend Linux for Dummies), or consider the [Introduction to Linux](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-linux-linuxfoundationx-lfs101x-2#.VJ4U814ADE) course offered by EdX.

Comment: This is actually really nice. I'm unsure why I was ever afraid of a CLI. I've grabbed a copy of both Chromium and Geany. Thanks!

Comment: It takes some getting used to (like anything new) and the course I mentioned will be a big help (I took it a few months ago - to evaluate it for a client and thought it well done). In time the command line will become your first choice.

Comment: The course has my interest

Comment: @VitaminYes `apt-cache search "text"` can also be helpful to find packages where you don't know the exact name.